# Save Data to text in grads After the print command

Tags: grads

In the grads software
After importing the geopotential data, we use the print command to display the data on the page. Is there a way to save this displayed data as text?

set gxout print

Output Taking Geopotential Values to Text File

```
sdfopen c:/Data/hgt.nc
set lon 0 120
set lat 0 80
set gxout print
d hgt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in script write:

---

```
'reinit'
'sdfopen C:\Data\hgt.nc'
'set lon 10 80'
'set lat 0 80'
'set gxout print'
'd hgt'
dummy=write('c:/Data/output.txt',result)
```

---